# Помогите не могу разобрать с Flex css и html не получаеться

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-items">
    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-items">
    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-items">
    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

вот как нужно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу разобрать как это сделать а с другими  источниками не получаеться

Comment: Что «это» и в чём конкретная проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Привет я хочу чтобы у меня было как на фото 2 колонки по 3 карточки у меня есть исходный код html но нет css 
html:
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: И какие возникли проблемы при написании css?

Comment: я пытался написать его и у меня выходила так что все карточки были в колонках то есть каждая карточка в новой колонке

Comment: @andreymal вы сможете чем то помочь?

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса нажав [edit], по скриншоту никто Вам помочь не сможет.

Comment: @andreymal я написал код который почему то не работает

Comment: В показанном сейчас html-коде отсутствует `flex-container` и всего один `card`, так что непонятно откуда тут колонкам браться-то

Comment: @andreymal можете дать исходный код ?

Comment: @andreymal Понял ну тогда что будет если я напишу flex-container 
и пропишу .flex-items:nth-child(1) и тд

Comment: @andreymal посмотрите код в теле вопроса

Comment: Теперь у вас все три карточки почему-то вложены друг в друга (третья во вторую, вторая в первую), что тоже вряд ли сможет породить какие-то колонки

Comment: @andreymal Ура я сделал спасибо за обьяснение я понял свои ошибки я забыл выделить название карточек а в css я очень глупо написал сейчас все испаривил и у меня все получилось осталось поработать с отступами)